# How plausibly could animals develop and normalize monozygotic twin births in their reproductive cycles?

Tags: biology

I'm currently trying to develop the world of a sci-fi story I'm working on, and a concept I've thought of adopting with the environment and characters is a common breeding system where identical twins (or sometimes not, asymmetric twins from the same egg have also been under consideration) are a commonplace byproduct of the world's evolution.

I'd like to know the plausibility of this. My idea is for two twins to be born with natural, pheromonal connections between one another. The sexual organs of the twins would be the same, thus preventing immediate inbreeding. I'd also envisioned [most] twins consistently having lifelong reliance on one another. i.e. I also want to know how reasonable it would be to expect them to coordinate efforts in the acquisition of food and evade potential predators. As for mating, I thought if they shared the exact same DNA there would be less ingrained concern over which gets to spread its genes. Would this be accurate?

Thanks in advance for anyone that tries to answer me. I'm doing what I can to keep things in the realm of reality, so it'd be much appreciated to know whether or not the universe I'm creating has a strong enough footing in the real world.

As a brief recap and outline, here's how I'd imagine this type of reproductive cycle working:

1) Two genders needed to reproduce.

2) Upon fertilization, the egg immediately moves to naturally develop monozygotic twins.

3) Both offspring share the same gender.

4) The twins try and operate as a pair from birth.

5) When any mate(s) is/are found, twins shouldn't need to compete between one another too much because of their identical DNA and the beneficial nature of their cooperation.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Melvin*! Interesting question. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: This exists in our own world. For some animals this is merely common, but for some, such as armadillos, monozygotic twins are the norm.

Answer (score 3):

#### 1) Two genders needed to reproduce.

#### 2) Upon fertilization, the egg immediately moves to naturally develop monozygotic twins.

#### 3) Both offspring share the same gender.

[Armadillos do that in our world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillo):

> (...) the nine-banded armadillo also exhibits delayed implantation, so the young are not typically born for eight months after mating. Most members of the genus Dasypus give birth to four monozygotic young (that is, identical quadruplets), but other species may have typical litter sizes that range from one to eight.

So this part is covered.

#### 4) The twins try and operate as a pair from birth.

#### 5) When any mate(s) is/are found, twins shouldn't need to compete between one another too much because of their identical DNA and the beneficial nature of their cooperation.

Items 4 and 5 may be accomplished if some species of armadillo evolved to be social. As it is now, they solitary animals.

---

Since we can find in our own real world features such as the ones you need, you don't need any suspension of disbelief nor handwaving to make it work for a fictional species.